# Troubleshooting 'Windows ERROR -- Possible Deadlock Condition"

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

I logged into a Windows 2003 Server machine this morning and saw one of those yellow pop-ups in the lower right that said:

> "Windows ERROR -- Possible Deadlock
>   Condition"

The server is my file server, other than that there is Symantec AV running on it and Netbackup 6 client.

*I don't see anything in the Event Viewer Logs, any recommendations on what to do next?*

I know what a deadlock is, but without any indication of *where* (OS, What application) it is happening, the error doesn't help much.

Comment: Lower left? Lower right?

Comment: mh: Right is Right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running SQL server? Exchange? Backup software? Could be a database issue.

Comment: SQL: No, Exchange: Not on this server, Backup: Yes (netbackup)

Comment: Is this the first time you've seen the error?

Comment: yes, also been getting high CPU alerts at night when the backups run, so maybe that...

Comment: I might start with a reboot and see if it keeps happening, if it doesn't, just let it go ...

Comment: I would definitely start troubleshooting with Netbackup, and go from there. Is it fully updated?

Answer (score 1):

You might be running into memory or threadpool deadlocks due to heavy contention.  If the problems continue I would run some perfmon traces with typical system resource counters.